# How to retrieve a single value from the database using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I'm using Dapper and trying to retrieve a short from the database and would like to do this without grabbing it from a collection.

I've got the following code, which doesn't work because `QueryAsync<short>` returns `IEnumerable<short>`.

```
short status;
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@ID", ID, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
    status = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<short>("SELECT [StatusID] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [ID] = @ID", parameters, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeoutInSeconds);
}
```

Can I get Dapper to return a single value, instead of a collection?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

FYI, Dapper has now added both `QuerySingle` and `QuerySingleAsync` as well as their corresponding `OrDefault` variants... usage for `QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync` is:

```
await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<short>(sql);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer, and keeps your code much cleaner than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Nice one, I've changed the accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 15):

Either you can use `ExecuteScalarAsync` or `Single()` 
with `ExecuteScalarAsync` you can retrieve a single value from database using Dapper.

```
short status;
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
  parameters.Add("@ID", ID, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

  await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
  status = await sqlConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync<short>("SELECT [StatusID] FROM     [MyTable] WHERE [ID] = @ID", parameters, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeoutInSeconds);
}
```

`Single()` can be used in this way

```
short status;
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
  parameters.Add("@ID", ID, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

  await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
  status = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<short>("SELECT [StatusID] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [ID] = @ID", parameters, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeoutInSeconds).Single();
}
```

Comment: You can use `QuerySingle` as well now.

Comment: @DavidMohundro Please add that as an answer - it's the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ExecuteScalar`:

```
status = await sqlConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync<short>("SELECT [StatusID] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [ID] = @ID", parameters, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeoutInSeconds)
```